# How I can get the temperature of pixels in degree Celsius for COLORMAP_JET in opencv with C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, colormap

I want to print the equivalent temperature **in kelvin** of a pixel of an image that is converted by COLORMAP_JET.

e.g. an image is `100 x 100` in dimension, then the temperature array be like,

```
temp[] = {
    { 104, 1000, 600, .........},
    { 34, ,234, 678, ..........},
    { ..........................},
    { ..........................}
}
```

I want to store those temperatures in an array named `temperature`.

```
    applyColorMap(img, im_color, COLORMAP_JET);
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
            temperature[count++] = ;/*get temperature here*/
        }
    }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The colormap filters aren't associated with temperatures. They are meant to give better visualization to grayscale images.

Comment: SO how can I convert an rgb image to a temperature image?

Comment: You need a thermographic camera to take a "temperature" image. A thermographic camera detects infrared radiation. A normal rgb camera detects visible light which doesn't really equate to temperature. A thermographic camera creates grayscale images. You can then take those images and apply a colormap filter to them to make them easier to view. Regarding the conversion of the grayscale values with temperature, that would depend on the camera being used.

Comment: Sorry to say, this is not what I wanted. I think my question isn't clear. Look at [this](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/). I want some **kelvin** value for a pixel.

Comment: That link is doing what my last comment states: They are taking a numeric data value (single channel) and applying a color map to it to make the information easier to visualize. The choices in the table don't correspond to the actual color of the object, the object is a "blackbody", meaning it doesn't emit visible radiation. Assuming you want to take their output image and convert it back to the original kelvin data, then you'd need to use the lookup table that they provided.

Comment: Ok. Pardon for my lack of knowledge regarding this field. According to this [link](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html), these temperatures corresponded with RGB values for a blackbody image. On the contrary, may I say that a normal `.jpg/.png` image having these RGB values will have the same `temperature` vice-versa so that I can generate a 2D temperature array for a given image (which is my actual goal)?

Comment: The point that I am trying to make is: if you use your cell phone camera to take a photo of a blue sky, it will have blue pixels. That doesn't mean that the temperature of the sky is 30,000 degrees Kelvin.